# Phonegap + Android: disable bounce and highlight effect on scrolling

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I've started an Adroid project with Phonegap following this guide:
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Android

There is an unpleasant effect when scrolling longer pages: a highlighting at the end of scrolling (covering header and footer) and a small bounce (which makes fixed position header and footer also bounce).

Is there a way to prevent both - bouncing and highlight - on Android using this implementation of Phonegap? I've seen solutions only for embedded WebView.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well you can add the following lines:

```
if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) {
    this.appView.setOverScrollMode(appView.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);
}
```

to the onCreate method of your Java class that extends from DroidGap it should get rid of the highlight at least and maybe the bounce too.

Comment: Thank you, it indeed did help, however it seems better to set it so: `this.appView.setOverScrollMode(View.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);`

Comment: You'll want to use my if statement as if this code tries to run on phones earlier than Gingerbread it will cause a problem.